# Backend currently unmounting

Tags: gvfs

When I try unmounting a network share, I get the message "Backend Currently Unmounting."

```
$ gvfs-mount -u .gvfs/SFTP\ for\ root\ on\ 2.2.2.2
Error unmounting mount: Backend currently unmounting
```

Is there a way to force unmount?

Comment: I guess one way is to kill whatever process are in there and then unmount it, but that seems a bit extreme.